# Cookies wont persist after phonegap app is closed

Tags: android, django, cordova, cookies, phonegap-build

i'm having a little problem with my phonegapp app on Android with python-django as backend. When i close the app i lost all the cookies that the server sets after the authentication (sessionid and csrftoken). 
So, every time i open the app i have to do the login procedure. I try to save the sessionid in localStorage and then create my own header but this is not allowed by XMLHttpRequest specification. I need a simple workout for doing something like this:

```
function get_csrf_token(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://www.mywebsite.com/token",
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", 'sessionid=' + window.localStorage["sessid"]);
    },

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
      alert(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
      alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    },
    success: function (token) {
      window.localStorage["token"] = token;
      return token;
    }
  });
}
```

Is this possibile with phonegap or i have to login every time i start the app?

Answer (score 0):

You really aught to be using a different authentication method when dealing with mobile. It's a lot easier to try token-based authentication. Essentially you have a form on your mobile app that takes their username/password and pass it to a view you design that ensures validity and then responds with a token that the app can include in all subsequent calls.

You can implement this in Django fairly easy with a custom authentication backend, or you can use Django Rest Framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication that has it built in.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is definitely possible.  It's impossible to set cookies on an XMLHttpRequest object.  But if you set the cookie using `document.cookie` first, it will be sent on the cookie header for every subsequent request.

```
function get_csrf_token(){
  document.cookie = 'sessionid=' + window.localStorage["sessid"];
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://www.mywebsite.com/token",
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
  ...
  });
}
```

The only thing you are going to want to watch out for while doing this is the possibility of an XSS attack. By storing the session id in localstorage, if your app were to have an XSS vulnerability, an attacker could possibly get the localstorage session id and send it to their server using JSONP or an image tag etc.  Since you are using phonegap, you can mitigate this problem by using a [whitelist policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) that will only allow requests to go to your known servers.